# Is the measure space $(\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}),\mu)$ complete where $\mu$ is the Lesbesgue measure?

Tags: measure-theory

Is the measure space $(\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}),\mu)$ complete where $\mu$ is the Lesbesgue measure?

I know that when a measure space is complete, all subsets of null sets must be measurable with measure $0$. For finite sets this is definitely true. I think that for subsets of uncountable null sets, like the Cantor set, this will be false. But I can't seem to find a specific subset of the Cantor set which is not measurable. On top of that, how do non-measurable sets look like in this particular case?

Kees

Comment: What is a measure? We need a measure when talking about null sets. Without measure, we can not distinguish null sets from elements in the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: of course, i totally forget. We use the lesbesque measure : 4\mu([a,b)) = b-a$

Comment: There are $2^{\aleph_0}$ Borel sets, whereas there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ subsets of the Cantor set, so there is a non-Borel subset of the Cantor set. However I guess finding such subset is *very* hard. Without axiom of choice, it is *consistent* with ZF that every subset of the reals is Borel. When assuming choice, you might construct such subset.

Comment: hmmmmm, i dont see exactly how you come up with these cardinality's though. They are both uncountable right?

Comment: Yes, but $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ is *strictly larger* than $2^{\aleph_0}$, by Cantor's theorem.

Comment: how does one see that the cardinality of the cantor set is $2^{2^{\aleph_{0}}}$

Comment: You may know that the cardinality of the Cantor set is $2^{\aleph_0}$. In general, the cardinality of the powerset (i.e. set of all subsets) of $A$ is $2^{|A|}$.